# How to uninstall matlab from ubuntu 14.04

Tags: uninstall, matlab

How can I uninstall matlab from Ubuntu 14.04?
Its not a licensed one I guess.

When I run: `sudo apt-get purge matlab-support`, it shows: `Matlab not installed`

Also tried `sudo apt-get purge matlab`

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: For an answer you will need to provide an answer to "How did you install it?". If not through apt then purge obviously does not work. Manual install? See if there is an uninstall script otherwise you use "rm"

Comment: Firstly , I unzipped the file using unzip "FILE"

Comment: Then , using sudo  ./ install i installed it.

Comment: @HarishBodduna since you did not install using apt, you cannot remove using apt.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :)

cd to etc directory

```
sudo ./lmdown or sudo bash lmdown
```

cd back to root

```
sudo rm /var/tmp/lm_TMW*
rm /usr/local/bin/matlab /usr/local/bin/mcc /usr/local/bin/mex /usr/local/bin/mbuild /usr/local/bin/matlab /usr/local/bin/mex
sudo apt-get purge matlab-support
```

or

```
sudo apt-get purge --auto-remove matlab-support
```

restart

let me know if this works

Comment: sudo ./lmdown not working neither sudo bash lmdown

Comment: does it work with out it ?

Comment: If it didn't work maybe its not there to begin with , try the rest of the commands and skip the first one and let me know what happens